# Query in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-query-language

I made a simple query function as this: =QUERY(range,"select *",1), in my Google Spreadsheet, but the results dose not show any letters, it shows only fields that contains numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Study this [link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?visit_id=1-636182685813914498-1998856292&hl=en-GB&rd=1)

> **Syntax**
>
> QUERY(data, query, [headers])
>
> data - The range of cells to perform the query on.
>
> Each column of data can only hold boolean, numeric (including
> date/time types) or string values.
>
> **In case of mixed data types in a single column, the majority data type
> determines the data type of the column for query purposes. Minority
> data types are considered null values.**

---

Just format your range as a plain text using **Format > Number > Plain text** option, the below images show how to do it:

[image]

[image]

[image]